# How to make an user send an invitation to chat to another user in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have my list of events in Firebase Database, in a field "interesados", the users who press like buton to that event.

[How events are in my DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CKwe.png)

In Android, I have my RecyclerVview with that list of users, I want my application make the "current user" make an invitation to chat to anyone in the list. (the list of "interesados")

I already have the code in android to chat between users. But What i look for is user1(im logged as users1), after see the list of people interested in that event, make an invitation to user3 to start a chat.
How i send this notification to user3, that user1 want to start a chat: Accept or Decline.

In the list of users, I already the uid(taken from facebook auth), name, etc.

I've been looking for but I only  found "Send notificacion to all users from writing especific text in Firebase Notification", but I don't want this.
Maybe I'm looking with a wrong tittle,If so  I'd like to know how should I look for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send user targeted push notifications. 
You can achieve this in two ways.

1. **Send notification to token**: When you receive registration token from GCM server, map it with the corresponding user id in your application server. Say, something like creating an API **registerUser(userID, token)**. Later send notification by calling an API **sendNotification(userID)**. In this API, you simply fetch the token corresponding to that user id and send a notification to that token from your app server. Visit here to setup an android client: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

   2.**Send notification to topic**: When you create a firebase user, simply subscribe the user in his UID.
   **FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(userUID)**. Later send notification to that user by sending notification to topic(here our topic is the user's UID) method. See this link for topic subscription: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

The notification sending options, which should be done from your application server, are described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message